# Java class.getRessource().getPath() adds a weird '/' at the begining of the URL

Tags: java, fonts, swt, getresource

I want to load a font in a SWT. My ttf file is in the `resources/fonts` directory of my Maven project. I try to load it like this:

```java
URL fontURL = MyClass.class.getResource("/fonts/myfont.ttf");
boolean fontLoaded = display.loadFont(fontURL.getPath());
```

But the resulting boolean is always false. I tried to prompt the result of `fontURL.getPath()`, and it is something like `/C:/Users/myuser/Documents/...`. If I copy this result in a String, remove the first / and try to call `display.loadFont()` with it, it works.

Another weird thing is that this is not the only resource I load this way. For example, this is how I load the icon of the window:

```java
URL iconURL = MyClass.class.getResource("/images/myicon.png");
Image icon = new Image(display, iconURL.getPath());
shell.setImage(icon);
```

And it works fine. The only file posing problem is the font file. Does anybody know why ?

Comment: Note: Loading using a file path may work while you have things in separate files for testing but when you build a jar containing everything it will stop working because resources in a jar are not files and can't be addressed using a file path. Is this just an SWT app you are building or is it an Eclipse plug-in (which have a different way of loading resources)?

Comment: Don't worry, I know that. The build result is a zip containing, among others, the JAR and the resources. It is an SWT app that I am building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for `/` at the beginning is that `getPath` of the `URL` class returns the URL path defined by [RFC 2396](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) (see [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html)).

As for why it's working for the `Image` constructor and not for `loadFont()` method, the answer can be found in the implementation.
The constructor uses `FileInputStream` which internally normalizes the path, whereas `loadFont()` has a native implementation for loading which does not support such path.

Since in both cases a file path is expected, what you want to do is normalize the path yourself using either `File` constructor or `Paths.get(url.toURI()).toString()` method.